# Sharing a WebDriver instance when using Selenium, TestNG, and Cucumber-JVM

Tags: java, selenium, testng, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to add Cucumber-JVM to a TestNG and Selenium project I've been working on, where I currently re-use browsers on a grid via a testsuite something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Grid" thread-count="2" parallel="tests">
    <test name="Firefox 27.0">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
        <parameter name="browser_version" value="27.0"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="[Test package name]"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
    <test name="IE 11">
        <parameter name="browser" value="IE"/>
        <parameter name="browser_version" value="11.0"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="[Test package name]"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Each test class in the package then takes the parameters in a setUp method in the base class which looks like this:

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"browser", "browser_version"})
public void setUp(String browser, String browser_version) throws MalformedURLException {
    // Do the setup with WebDriver and assign to an object property
}
```

However, I'd like to have a static or injected class that is shared between all the test classes to avoid re-initialising the browser each time, which should also let me share the WebDriver instance between the various step definition files. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Pico Container, which is packaged with Cucumber-JVM.

Then in the constructor of your test classes you can ask for the Driver:

```
public class TestClass {

    WebDriver driver;

    public TestClass(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

PicoContainer will automatically pass an instance of the webdriver to the class, any other classes that have a similar constructor will also get the same instance.

Link to the documentation: http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/constructor-injection.html

Comment: Can I use this to pass in the variation configuration options from the TestNG suite files?

Comment: not sure. Could you perhaps wrap the WebDriver in your own class, that could retrieve the TestNG config. Then pass that class into your tests using the constructor injection provided by PicoContainer?

Comment: Are you able to read browser and browser version values from parameter tags of testng.xml and use it in stepdefs of cucumber?